# VNC Suddenly stops receiving Connections

Tags: 10.04, vnc, lts

I have a fit PC that essentially runs just a subversion server and as a test server for web applications.  I upgraded a while back to 10.04 LTS and no issues.  I don't have any keyboard or monitor installed on it, I just access the desktop through VNC, and while a little slow, it works perfectly fine.

Suddenly, today, I'm having an issue accessing Subversion.  I tried to VNC to the machine, but it's refusing connections.

I've SSH into the server and reboot, but still no dice.  I can manage OK (usually) on my own with the desktop, but I don't use the terminal very often, so I'm kind of stuck now and hoping someone has an idea...

I can confirm that the VNC Server is being started at startup.  I run netstat and can see the following:

(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5901            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4261/Xtightvnc  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4261/Xtightvnc  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:60888           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::6000                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Which I presume to mean VNC is listening to port 5901.

Don't know what else to do from here.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so I seem to have resolved this.  The Subversion error was indicating a lack of disk space, which made no sense because I couldn't figure out where all the space was going.

Turns out there was a hidden file that was 110GB. The file was .xsession-errors and was FILLED with lines like such:

11/01/2012 07:38:23 AM Authentication deferred - ignoring client message

It had been outputting about 13000+ per SECOND.  I cleared the file and rebooted and subversion came back to life as did VNC.

While I haven't solved WHY this happened, I am at least temporarily, able to work.